# Web Essentials SCSS compile error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I am trying to compile the SCSS files in a projetc using Visual Studio 2013 and Web Essentials. Here is the error I am getting in the visual studio output window is

```
Something went wrong reaching: http://127.0.0.1:52658/?service=SCSS&sourceFileName=C:\Development\KnockApp\KnockApp\KnockApp.Web\Content\scss\directory.scss&targetFileName=C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Temp\3510b388-06aa-48bb-b517-e1442399e924.css&mapFileName=C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Temp\3510b388-06aa-48bb-b517-e1442399e924.css.map&precision=5&outputStyle=expanded& 

SCSS: directory.scss compilation failed: The service failed to respond to this request          
      Possible cause: Syntax Error!
```

The SCSS files come from a third party theme and they use Compass, I have included the compass files in my project. I also have node and node-sass installed on the machine.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Compass requires more than just the Sass files, there are a number of functions that are written in Ruby.  If you're trying to use sprites or any of [the helper functions](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/), you can't use node-sass.

Comment: Web Essentials update 4 has Ruby compiling as an alternative to node. I've tried using it unsuccessfully, but perhaps you'll have more luck with it.

Comment: No buddy, no luck at all. I installed ruby and managed to get compass working but web essentials is still monitoring the folder even when I ask it not to and the ruby compiler still b1+ches about the scss files.

Answer (score 11):

Got same error and found solution.
Web Essentials uses node.exe to build SCSS, but this service is crashed when tried to compile some partial SCSS with unresolved dependencies. 
After that Visual Studio logs 'Something went wrong reaching' messages on each build, to fix this error just kill all 'node.exe' processes and build main SCSS file again.

Comment: Wow, nice spot. I'll try this when next I do any project that requires compiling scss. thanks

Comment: This one saved me few hours of searching.